# Detached border due to long inline-block in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

https://jsfiddle.net/eaj7szv8/7/

If I put a long `display: inline-block` element inside a span in Firefox, the content is pushed to the next line. However, the `left-border` stays on the previous line, detaching it from the bordered content. Chromium pushes the border to the next line along with the rest of the content. How do I get Firefox to have the same behavior as Chromium?

#### Edit:

Context: I have an `inline-block` `span` courtesy of MathJax inside a bordered `span` in a paragraph. So yes, the inner span is supposed to `inline-block`, and yes, the outer span is supposed to be `inline`.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because a `span` has a default display value of `inline`. If you want the border to extend like you expect it to, you'll need to define `display: inline-block;` on the outer span.

Comment: Are you saying that Chrome/Chromium has the wrong behavior then?

Comment: The CSS spec isn't definitive down to every fine detail, without looking it up, this probably falls under the category implementation-specific.